# Query to show stock based on previous transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please I need your help..

for an Objective
match SO (Sales Order) quantity to PO (Purchase Order) quantity based on FIFO (First In, First Out) where the first stock items purchased must be the first items sold.

I have a table Stock which use to track the movement of stock in and out of imaginary stock warehouse. The warehouse is initially empty, and stock then moves into the warehouse as a result of a stock purchase (‘IN’) and stock moves out of the warehouse when it is sold (‘OUT’). Each type of stock item is identified by an ItemID. Each movement of stock in or out of the warehouse, due to a purchase or sale of a given item, results in a row being added to the Stock table, uniquely identified by the value in the StockID identify column, and describing how many items were added or removed and the date of the transaction.

Table stock :

```
 StockId    DocumentID  ItemID  TranDate    TranCode    Quantity
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    1       PO001       A021    2016.01.01  IN          3
    4       SO010       A021    2016.01.02  OUT         2
    2       PO002       A021    2016.01.10  IN          7
    3       PO003       A021    2016.02.01  IN          9
    5       SO011       A021    2016.02.11  OUT         8
    6       SO012       A023    2016.02.12  OUT         6
```

How could I write a query to give output like the table below?

```
SOID    POID    Quantity
------------------------
SO010   PO001   2
SO011   PO001   1
SO011   PO002   7
SO012   PO003   6
```

Comment: There is no way to answer this question since you don't explain the rules for selecting the values in the second table.

Comment: Ugh. You're clearly looking for a query that figures out the running totals of your quantities and what 'IN' POIDs correspond to the 'OUT' SOIDs based on this... What I would recommend is rethinking how you store your data. You would have better luck keeping track of the information you want to keep track of if you stored the in/out transactions properly.

Comment: How should it be determined which `SO` values of `DocumentID` correspond to which `PO` values? Does each `SOnnn` just relate to the last `PO` for the same `ItemID`? Also, `SO012` is associated with `PO003` in your example output, but the two are for different `ItemID`s - is this correct? When do the `A023` Items come into stock? They're only mentioned on `SO012` and not on any `PO` record...

Comment: table Stock which use to track the movement of stock in and out of imaginary stock warehouse. warehouse is initially empty,& stock then moves into the warehouse as a result of a stock purchase (‘IN’) & stock moves out of the warehouse when it is sold (‘OUT’).Each type of stock item is identified by an ItemID. Each movement of stock in or out of the warehouse, due to a purchase or sale of a given item,results in a row being added to the Stock table,uniquely identified by the value in the StockID identify column,and describing how many items were added or removed and the date of the transaction.

Comment: and for an objective, match SO (Sales Order) quantity to PO (Purchase Order) quantity based on FIFO (First In, First Out) where the first stock items purchased must be the first items sold.

Comment: It is a standard stock calcs if I got it right. Each out operation decrements the first available entry from ins. Second out is 2 and it decrements first input and 1 is remainig. Secound out is 8. Since first input still has 1 remaining it decrements it and then decrements 7 from second in etc. I am confused about last out. Why it decrements third in with different item?

Comment: When I was investigated about stocks implementation I came across this ands I am sure it will be useful:  https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/set-based-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-sql-problem/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seeing as no one else has given this a go, I figure I'll post something that resembles an answer (I believe).

Essentially, what you want to do is keep track of the number of things you have in stock and the number of things that have gone out, based on the date (I haven't accounted for multiple things coming in or going out on the same date, though).

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE 
(
    DocumentID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    TranCode VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    TranDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL
); -- I'm ignoring the other columns here because they don't seem important to your overall needs.

INSERT @Table (DocumentID, TranCode, TranDate, Quantity)
VALUES 
    ('PO001', 'IN', '2016-01-01', 3),
    ('SO010', 'OUT', '2016-01-02', 2),
    ('PO002', 'IN', '2016-01-10', 7),
    ('PO003', 'IN', '2016-02-01', 9),
    ('SO011', 'OUT', '2016-02-11', 8),
    ('SO012', 'OUT', '2016-02-12', 6);

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DocumentID,
            TranCode,
            TranDate,
            Quantity,
            RunningQuantity = -- Determine the current IN/OUT totals.
                (
                    SELECT SUM(Quantity)
                    FROM @Table 
                    WHERE TranCode = T.TranCode
                    AND TranDate <= T.TranDate
                ),
            PrevQuantity = -- Keep track of the previous IN/OUT totals.
                (
                    SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Quantity), 0)
                    FROM @Table
                    WHERE TranCode = T.TranCode
                    AND TranDate < T.TranDate
                )
    FROM @Table T
)
SELECT Outgoing.DocumentID,
        Incoming.DocumentID,
        Quantity =
            CASE WHEN Outgoing.RunningQuantity <= Incoming.RunningQuantity AND Outgoing.PrevQuantity >= Incoming.PrevQuantity
                 THEN Outgoing.RunningQuantity - Outgoing.PrevQuantity
                 WHEN Outgoing.RunningQuantity <= Incoming.RunningQuantity AND Outgoing.PrevQuantity < Incoming.PrevQuantity
                 THEN Outgoing.RunningQuantity - Incoming.PrevQuantity
                 ELSE Incoming.RunningQuantity - Outgoing.PrevQuantity
            END
FROM CTE Outgoing
JOIN CTE Incoming ON
        Incoming.TranCode = 'IN'
    AND Incoming.RunningQuantity > Outgoing.PrevQuantity
    AND Incoming.PrevQuantity < Outgoing.RunningQuantity
WHERE Outgoing.TranCode = 'OUT'
ORDER BY Outgoing.TranDate;
```

Note: I would highly recommend you keep track of the information in a better way. For example, create a table that actually details which orders took what from which other orders (an order transaction table or something), because while it's not impossible to achieve what you want with the way your data is structured, it's much less complicated if you just store more helpful data.